# Spark scala faster way to groupbykey and sort rdd values

Tags: scala, sorting, apache-spark, group-by, rdd

I have a rdd with format of each row `(key, (int, double))`

I would like to transform the rdd into `(key, ((int, double), (int, double) ...) )`

Where the the values in the new rdd is the top N values pairs sorted by the double

So far I came up with the solution below but it's really slow and runs forever, it works fine with smaller rdd but now the rdd is too big

```
val top_rated = test_rated.partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(4)).sortBy(_._2._2).groupByKey()
            .mapValues(x => x.takeRight(n))
```

I wonder if there are better and faster ways to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way is probably `aggregateByKey`

```
type K = String
type V = (Int, Double)
val rdd: RDD[(K, V)] = ???

//TODO: implement a function that adds a value to a sorted array and keeps top N elements. Returns the same array
def addToSortedArray(arr: Array[V], newValue: V): Array[V] = ??? 
//TODO: implement a function that merges 2 sorted arrays and keeps top N elements. Returns the first array
def mergeSortedArrays(arr1: Array[V], arr2: Array[V]): Array[V] = ??? //TODO

val result: RDD[(K, Array[(Int, Double)])] = rdd.aggregateByKey(zeroValue = new Array[V](0))(seqOp = addToSortedArray, combOp = mergeSortedArrays)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're interested only in the top-N values in your RDD, I would suggest that you avoid sorting across the entire RDD.  In addition, use the more performing `reduceByKey` rather than `groupByKey` if at all possible.  Below is an example using a `topN` method, borrowed from this [blog](https://blog.genuine.com/2018/06/generic-top-n-elements-in-scala/):

```
def topN(n: Int, list: List[(Int, Double)]): List[(Int, Double)] = {
  def bigHead(l: List[(Int, Double)]): List[(Int, Double)] = list match {
    case Nil => list
    case _ => l.tail.foldLeft( List(l.head) )( (acc, x) =>
        if (x._2 <= acc.head._2) x :: acc else acc :+ x
      )
  }
  def update(l: List[(Int, Double)], e: (Int, Double)): List[(Int, Double)] = {
    if (e._2 > l.head._2) bigHead((e :: l.tail)) else l
  }
  list.drop(n).foldLeft( bigHead(list.take(n)) )( update ).sortWith(_._2 > _._2)
}

val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("a", (1, 10.0)), ("a", (4, 40.0)), ("a", (3, 30.0)), ("a", (5, 50.0)), ("a", (2, 20.0)),
  ("b", (3, 30.0)), ("b", (1, 10.0)), ("b", (4, 40.0)), ("b", (2, 20.0))
))

val n = 2

rdd.
  map{ case (k, v) => (k, List(v)) }.
  reduceByKey{ (acc, x) => topN(n, acc ++ x) }.
  collect
// res1:  Array[(String, List[(Int, Double)])] =
//   Array((a,List((5,50.0), (4,40.0))), (b,List((4,40.0), (3,30.0)))))
```